# How to deal with a sprawling, ginormously broad question that is confused and hard to understand?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I stumbled upon a question by a novice Java user that starts in one place, traverses a vast landscape of technologies, muddles the issue with several additional questions and in general is rather hard to pin down to 1 specific question. The question I talk about is the following:

[How can I use Maven to automatically download any needed dependencies of my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7233790/1996)

I wanted to clean this up somehow but I am not sure where to start: do you edit this down to one coherent question out of the soup of issues? In general it seems to me his question has nothing to do with Maven but rather with how to set up a particular small Java project. However, existing answers already go into (mostly irrelevant) side issues regarding Maven.

Perhaps there are some precedents for this? Should I attempt some form of editing or just flag as "very low quality"?

Comment: I take it the OP's edit didn't help?

Comment: You should NARQ on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this what the **Not a Real Question** close reason was invented for?

---

[image]

Comment: Doh, I'm a tool for missing that option. Much obliged.